# View call stack of built-in Android app via Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth, stack-trace, l2cap

I am trying view the call stack of the Android bluetooth settings/setup app.

Android 3.0 is able to pair with a bluetooth keyboard however the SDK does not expose this functionality. From what I understand, the keyboard uses the HID profile which requires an L2CAP socket. The SDK only exposes an RFCOMM socket.

I want to see what the built-in bluetooth setup app is doing to connect to a HID device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only debug applications that have [debuggable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#debug) set to `true`.